# Sum the leave hours from the presence in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arraylist

I want to calculate the leave hours of each employee.

I have the following Tables:

**attendance** with (id, empid, check_in, check_out, date) columns

**leave** with(id,empid,reason,time_long from_date, to_date) columns

**employee** with (id,name,....) columns

This is my query:

```
select `emp`.*, `p`.*, `a`.*, `l`.`id` as `leaveId`, `l`.`time_long` as `leaveLong`, `l`.`from_date` as `leaveFrom`, `l`.`to_date` as `leaveTo` from `employee` as `emp` inner join `attendance` as `a` on `emp`.`id` = `a`.`empid`  left join `leave` as `l` on `emp`.`id` = `l`.`empid` where `a`.`date` between 2019-03-01 and 2019-03-31 order by `emp`.`id` asc)
```

the query returns the following records.

```
[
   {
      "log_id": 1310,
      "name": "ahmad",
      "empid": 3,
      "check_in": "11:56",
      "check_out": "17:25",
      "date": "2019-03-23",
      "time_long": "5:28",
      "leaveId": 5,
      "leaveLong": 16,
      "leaveFrom": "2019-03-15",
      "leaveTo": "2019-03-17"
    },
    {
      "log_id": 1311,
      "name": "ahmad",
      "empid": 3,
      "check_in": "07:14",
      "check_out": "17:24",
      "date": "2019-03-24",
      "time_long": "10:9",
      "leaveId": 5,
      "leaveLong": 16,
      "leaveFrom": "2019-03-15",
      "leaveTo": "2019-03-17"
    },{
      "log_id": 1312,
      "name": "ahmad",
      "empid": 3,
      "check_in": "06:58",
      "check_out": "17:21",
      "date": "2019-03-25",
      "time_long": "10:23"
      "leaveId": 5,
      "leaveLong": 16,
      "leaveFrom": "2019-03-15",
      "leaveTo": "2019-03-17"
    },{
      "log_id": 1313,
      "name": "ahmad",
      "empid": 3,
      "check_in": "07:58",
      "check_out": "17:21",
      "date": "2019-03-26",
      "time_long": "9:23"
      "leaveId": 15,
      "leaveLong": 8.0,
      "leaveFrom": "2019-03-28",
      "leaveTo": "2019-03-29"
    },
    {
      "log_id": 1314,
      "name": "ahmad",
      "empid": 3,
      "check_in": "07:58",
      "check_out": "17:21",
      "date": "2019-03-26",
      "time_long": "9:23"
      "leaveId": 15,
      "leaveLong": 8.0,
      "leaveFrom": "2019-03-28",
      "leaveTo": "2019-03-29"
    },
    {
      "log_id": 1315,
      "name": "ahmad",
      "empid": 3,
      "check_in": "08:00",
      "check_out": "16:00",
      "date": "2019-03-27",
      "time_long": "8:00"
      "leaveId": 15,
      "leaveLong": 8.0,
      "leaveFrom": "2019-03-28",
      "leaveTo": "2019-03-29"
    }
    { ... }
  ]
```

So I expect the following result from this output:

Vacation for employee with ID 3 = 24 hours

Comment: Do you intend to do this in JavaScript or PHP? You tagged both.

Comment: can somebody explain logic behind this line `leave long for employee with ID 3 = 24 hours and leave long fro employee with ID 8 = 0 hours`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope that you didn't share confidential or classified data in this question. Furthermore please take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be good to share what you have tried so far and potential errors you encountered.

Comment: Why for id 3 the expected answer is 24? shouldn't it be 16 + 16 + 16 + 8.0 + 8.0 = 64, or do you want to check also uniqueness?

Comment: @Qirel I am working in php but I tagged java script also because i just want to know the concept. then I can code it in both

Comment: i guess you want summation of leavelong for every employee with same id and if it is null return as 0 right ?

Comment: exaclty you are right @TapanDave

Comment: We need some additional information here on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: simply, I want summation of leaveLong for every employee only if leaveId is different. for example, in records which leaveId is 5 leaveLong is 16 I want only 16 once, in records which leaveId is 5 leaveLong is 8 I want only 8 once, so the result for employee with ID 3 is 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can use foreach to group data with empid,

```
$temp = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // fetching all data as per empid and leave id 
    $temp[$value['empid']][$value['leaveId']][] = $value['leaveLong'];
}
$result = [];
foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        // fetching max value for empid and leave id
        $result[$key][$key1] = max($value1);        
    }   
}
// summing per emp id
$result = array_map("array_sum", $result);
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PEHZj).

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [3] => 24
    [8] => 0
)
```

Comment: I want take one 16 from all records where empid = 3 and leaveId = 5 and take one 8 from all records where empid = 3 and leaveId = 15 then sum leaveLongs so in this case the result will be 24 for employee ID 3

Comment: I made changes as per your requirement. Once see demo and output.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript**

**EDIT:** Changed the code to fit the newest requirements.

What is the concept? We use `reduce` to accumulate the results in an object. Basically, we take an object's `empid` and make a key inside the object out of it. If the key already exists we take the existing value of the key and add the current `leaveLong` to it OR if the key doesn't exist yet we start our value at `0` but nonetheless still add the current `leaveLong` and by that create a key-value pair.

`(a[c.empid] || 0)` can be read as: *use the value of the given key **if** defined **else** use 0 as a value*.

So when `reduce` ran through our whole array of objects we have an object that holds all `empid`'s as keys and their respective leaveLong values as a sum value.

**EDIT:** Before that we have to `filter`. We simply find the first occurrence of the leaveId and filter out all the rest.

```js
var arr = [{"log_id":1310,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"11:56","check_out":"17:25","date":"2019-03-23","time_long":"5:28","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":16,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-15","leaveTo":"2019-03-17"},{"log_id":1311,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"07:14","check_out":"17:24","date":"2019-03-24","time_long":"10:9","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":16,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-15","leaveTo":"2019-03-17"},{"log_id":1312,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"06:58","check_out":"17:21","date":"2019-03-25","time_long":"10:23","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":16,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-15","leaveTo":"2019-03-17"},{"log_id":1313,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"07:58","check_out":"17:21","date":"2019-03-26","time_long":"9:23","leaveId":15,"leaveLong":8.0,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-28","leaveTo":"2019-03-29"},{"log_id":1314,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"07:58","check_out":"17:21","date":"2019-03-26","time_long":"9:23","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":8.0,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-28","leaveTo":"2019-03-29"},{"log_id":1315,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"08:00","check_out":"16:00","date":"2019-03-27","time_long":"8:00","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":8.0,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-28","leaveTo":"2019-03-29"},{"log_id":1316,"name":"Neda Mohammad","fname":"Gada Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473758.jpg","title":"Pharmacist","description":null,"empid":8,"check_in":"07:36","check_out":"17:57","date":"2019-03-25","time_long":"10:20","leaveId":null,"leaveLong":null,"leaveFrom":null,"leaveTo":null,},{"log_id":1317,"name":"Neda Mohammad","fname":"Gada Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473758.jpg","title":"Pharmacist","description":null,"empid":8,"check_in":"08:00","check_out":"16:00","date":"2019-03-26","time_long":"8:00","leaveId":null,"leaveLong":null,"leaveFrom":null,"leaveTo":null,},{"log_id":1318,"name":"Neda Mohammad","fname":"Gada Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473758.jpg","title":"Pharmacist","description":null,"empid":8,"check_in":"08:00","check_out":"16:00","date":"2019-03-27","time_long":"8:00","leaveId":null,"leaveLong":null,"leaveFrom":null,"leaveTo":null,}];

let res = arr.filter((v,i) => arr.findIndex(o => o.leaveId == v.leaveId) == i)  
             .reduce((a,c) => {a[c.empid] = (a[c.empid] || 0) + c.leaveLong; return a},{})

console.log(res)
```

**If** you need an array as an answer, put the object into `Object.entries`.

```js
var arr = [{"log_id":1310,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"11:56","check_out":"17:25","date":"2019-03-23","time_long":"5:28","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":16,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-15","leaveTo":"2019-03-17"},{"log_id":1311,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"07:14","check_out":"17:24","date":"2019-03-24","time_long":"10:9","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":16,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-15","leaveTo":"2019-03-17"},{"log_id":1312,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"06:58","check_out":"17:21","date":"2019-03-25","time_long":"10:23","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":16,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-15","leaveTo":"2019-03-17"},{"log_id":1313,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"07:58","check_out":"17:21","date":"2019-03-26","time_long":"9:23","leaveId":15,"leaveLong":8.0,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-28","leaveTo":"2019-03-29"},{"log_id":1314,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"07:58","check_out":"17:21","date":"2019-03-26","time_long":"9:23","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":8.0,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-28","leaveTo":"2019-03-29"},{"log_id":1315,"name":"ahmad","fname":"Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473469.jpg","title":"Doctor","description":null,"empid":3,"check_in":"08:00","check_out":"16:00","date":"2019-03-27","time_long":"8:00","leaveId":5,"leaveLong":8.0,"leaveFrom":"2019-03-28","leaveTo":"2019-03-29"},{"log_id":1316,"name":"Neda Mohammad","fname":"Gada Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473758.jpg","title":"Pharmacist","description":null,"empid":8,"check_in":"07:36","check_out":"17:57","date":"2019-03-25","time_long":"10:20","leaveId":null,"leaveLong":null,"leaveFrom":null,"leaveTo":null,},{"log_id":1317,"name":"Neda Mohammad","fname":"Gada Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473758.jpg","title":"Pharmacist","description":null,"empid":8,"check_in":"08:00","check_out":"16:00","date":"2019-03-26","time_long":"8:00","leaveId":null,"leaveLong":null,"leaveFrom":null,"leaveTo":null,},{"log_id":1318,"name":"Neda Mohammad","fname":"Gada Mohammad","photo":"images/user_profile//1550473758.jpg","title":"Pharmacist","description":null,"empid":8,"check_in":"08:00","check_out":"16:00","date":"2019-03-27","time_long":"8:00","leaveId":null,"leaveLong":null,"leaveFrom":null,"leaveTo":null,}];

let res = Object.entries(
              arr.filter((v,i) => arr.findIndex(o => o.leaveId == v.leaveId) == i)
                 .reduce((a,c) => {a[c.empid] = (a[c.empid] || 0) + c.leaveLong; return a},{}))

console.log(res)
```

In both cases you can replace `(a,c)` with `(a, { empid, leaveLong})` and adjust the function accordingly. But that is just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

for javascript

suppose we stored the data in empLeave

```
// Assuming we stored the data in a variable empLeave

// fetch the data in a object format
let empLeaveArray = JSON.parse(empLeave)

// declare empty object
let result = {} 

// loop through every object in the data i.e every leave sanctioned
empLeaveArray.forEach((ele) => {
// if the employee has already taken a leave add the leave to it
if(ele.empid in result)
   result[ele.empid] += ele.leavelong
// if employee has not taken the leave already add the employee to the object
else
   result[ele.empid] = ele.leavelong
})

for (let key in result) {
  console.log("employee " + key + " has taken " + result[key] + "leaves");
}
```